# How to display a string with space in an input?

Tags: html, django

I have a field "comment" in my site and I want to make it editable. To do that, I use an input field and with a javascript function it is saved in my database. However sometimes a comment has already been saved and I want to display it the user but it only displays the first word, it means Nothing is dispayed after the first space even if there is no problem in the database.

```
       <input id ="comment"
               class="w3-col round subsection-overview w3-hover-shadow"
               data-url="{{ request.path }}"
               onKeyPress="saveComment('data-url',this, '{{object.pk}}')"
               value ={{object.comment | default:''}} >

        </input>
```

Below the input field, there is the real value of the comment

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp6BF.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around your value attribute:

```
value="{{object.comment | default:''}}" >
```

Also, the default should not be necessary:

```
value="{{object.comment}}" >
```